# How to know if the network image is already loaded?

Tags: flutter

I want to animate Network image but i don't want to start the animation until the image is loaded, is there a way to know if it's loaded like a listener or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [Image.network](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image)'s [ImageLoadingBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageLoadingBuilder.html),

```
Image.network(imageURL,fit: BoxFit.cover,
  loadingBuilder:(BuildContext context, Widget child,ImageChunkEvent loadProgress) {
  if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: loadProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null ? 
             loadProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded / loadProgress.expectedTotalBytes
             : null,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I did't know about the `loadingProgress` parameter i think that will do the trick, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*Use [FadeInImage](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) to check image is loaded or not, and also can place placeholder before it...*

Comment: If id did that i will be animating the placeholder